# Custom saving parameters in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a survey controller which gathers `questions`, `answers` and the `user` who answered them into a `UserSurveyAnswer` modal.

I'm trying to expand it to allow text answers also (when required). Currently, you can tick any number of the provided answers, but I'm struggling to extend it to allow text answers (`:text_answer`)

At the moment, I'm pointing to this function from my controller

user_survey_answer.rb

```
 def self.update_answer(user_param, user_id)
    begin
      user_param[:survey].each do |survey|
        survey_id = survey[:id]
        survey[:question].each do |qs|
          question_id = qs[:id]
          answer_ids = qs[:answer_ids]
          answer_ids.collect{|answer_id| self.create({:user_id => user_id, :survey_id =>survey_id, :question_id => question_id, :answer_id => answer_id}) }

              #new bit, which doesn't work
            qs[:answer].each do |text_answer|
              self.create({:user_id => user_id, :survey_id =>survey_id, :question_id => question_id, :answer_id => text_answer[:id], :text_answer => text_answer[:text_answer]})
            end
              #end new bit

        end
      end
      return true
    rescue Exception => exc
      return false
    end
  end
```

Here is how the server is showing the information coming through.

```
"user"=>{"survey"=>[
    {"id"=>"1", "question"=>[
        {"id"=>"1", "answer_ids"=>["1"]}
    ]
    },
    {"id"=>"2", "question"=>[
        {"id"=>"2", "answer"=>[
            {"id"=>"2", "text_answer"=>"dwqdw"}
        ]
        }
    ]}
]}
```

Any ideas on how I can make the above information (in particular, the second part) save into my `UserSurveyAnswer` modal?

EDIT: Full UserSurveyAnswer Modal

```
class UserSurveyAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => [:survey_id, :question_id, :answer_id]

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :survey
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :answer

  def self.update_answer(user_param, user_id)
    begin
      user_param[:survey].each do |survey|
        survey_id = survey[:id]
        survey[:question].each do |qs|
          question_id = qs[:id]
          answer_ids = qs[:answer_ids]
          answer_ids.collect{|answer_id| self.create({:user_id => user_id, :survey_id =>survey_id, :question_id => question_id, :answer_id => answer_id}) }

          text_answer = qs[:answer]
          UserSurveyAnswer.create(user_id: user_id, survey_id: survey_id, question_id: question_id, answer_id: text_answer[:id], text_answer: text_answer[:text_answer])


        end
      end
      return true
    rescue Exception => exc
      return false
    end
  end


end
```

Comment: This is definitely a non-railsy way to do it. I don't have time to write out the full answer now but look into tutorials on 'nested forms' and the method 'accepts_nested_attributes_for'. Rails can automagically create all the associations in the submission including any validation on the child models.

Comment: I know this is hacked a lot. I had a really hard time getting it to work with dynamic form types for the answers (to allow check boxes, select and radio buttons).

Comment: An alternative is to set up nested attributes/relationships on the models and just build a custom hash on the controller side before creating the UserSurveyAnswer. As long as the params hash is formatted correctly the nested models will be created correctly and you don't need to worry about the form helpers at all.

Comment: That's a great idea. The whole form is a mess at the moment. If I can save from the current hash (or minor tweaking) that would be ideal. Otherwise I will rewrite it all and extract a custom hash.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd use nested attributes so all of this is automatically saved instead of you doing all of it manually. However, I'm not sure the line `self.create` makes much sense. I've never actually created an object from the model before. If I understand your associations correctly, you should put:

```
UserSurveyAnswer.create(user_id: user_id, survey_id: survey_id, question_id: question_id, answer_id: text_answer[:id], text_answer: text_answer[:text_answer])
```

Edit: So I'd also change the line before it to:

```
answer_ids.collect{|answer_id| UserSurveyAnswer.create(user_id: user_id, survey_id: survey_id, question_id: question_id, answer_id: answer_id) }
```

Comment: Apologies, text_answer is a field in UserSurveyAnswer. Not a modal.

Comment: Ok, so I updated my answer. If it doesn't work, can you edit your post to add your `UserSurveyAnswer` model?

Comment: Thank you! That's looking good, but for some reason, it's not looping around qs[:answer]. I will update my post now.

Comment: What do you mean it's not looping? In your example params, there is only one `qs[:answer]` per question, so there is no looping. If there was more than one, the `qs[:answer].each do |text_answer|` would take care of it.

Comment: I mean it's not even going to the qs[:answer].each do |text_answer| part. As if it's not finding anything in qs[:answer]

Comment: You're right, there's no need for the loop, I've removed that in the bottom edit of the UserSurverAnswer.rb modal. Though it's still not saving and the console is giving me no hints. it's not even trying to save

Answer (score 0):

I took it out of the modal and realised that when a text question exists, the answer_ids do not and so the function was failing on the first save line:

```
answer_ids.collect{|answer_id| self.create({:user_id => user_id, :survey_id =>survey_id, :question_id => question_id, :answer_id => answer_id}) }
```

Once i added in exception handling for this (and subsequent handling for the second save) it all worked!

Thank you to @ryan k for your help